# Is it OK to have a default namespace (xmlns) AND a prefixed namespace pointing to the same URI?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, domdocument, xml-namespaces

We're trying to generate some namespaced XML (attributes and all) but we're noticing some issues when outputting prefixes with both SimpleXML and DOMDocument in PHP. This is our test output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root xmlns:a="http://default" xmlns:b="http://extra" xmlns="http://default">
  <a:test_default>alpha</a:test_default>
  <b:test_extra>bravo</b:test_extra>
</root>
```

The reason I ask - we wanted to include the attributes in the namespace, but we're aware that attributes do not take the namespace of their containing element. We normally have a default namespace for our nodes. Thus, we concluded a prefix namespaced declaration would also be needed. However, when generating XML via SimpleXML or DOMDocument, prefixes are never added to the attributes.

Is there a better way? We were trying to avoid prefixing every element in the XML - utilising the default to make the content more readable.

Comment: !! "more readable": XML's not meant to be readable. You build the tree, call a library and it sends the tree to be reconstituted somewhere else. By design, it should work, and it's a black box.

Comment: @Nicholas I don't think its fair to say "XML's not meant to be readable". The specification does not state this, and I don't think it's a bad objective to prevent superfluous verbosity if it makes the content easier to understand.

Comment: Being a text format is just a handy debugging feature. If you want short, use zlib or gzip or whatever. If your library uses lots of prefixes, well, it's allowed to, and it's not your business to mess with its output if it's valid. If you want to implement it using other optional ways of serialising the data, then implement it yourself. The PHP library does not do the cleanest output, we all know that, but you picked XML output to guarantee it could be parsed at the other end, not eye-balled on the way.

Comment: XML is not HTML. The committee never intended it to be hand-generated nor human read. It's machine to machine. You can't parse it reliably by sight. Open in Firefox or any XML editor to get a tree view if you want to read or edit it. How many optional prefixes our implementations use is none of our concern. I'm being very rude and harsh here, so please don't be offended, but I'd rather speak out for safety and maintainability than prettiness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's quite OK to do this. It's often done in XSD, for example.